# How to make a border to circle in css

Tags: html, css

How to make a border to circle in css , Presently it is in Square shape , So I want to make it circle

```html
    color: white;
    left: 52px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 195, 255);
   
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

*See the sample image*

[image: See the sample image]

Comment: It is expected you do a little research and searching before you post a question.  A simple [google for your title](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=How+to+make+a+border+to+circle+in+css&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&oq=How+to+make+a+border+to+circle+in+css&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j0.3207j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) will bring up a lot of answers.  Please try put in a little more effort before posting a question next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set width and height to an equal value und add `border-radius: 50%;`.

```css
.circle {
width: 60px;
height:60px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `border-radius: 20px` changing the 20px higher or lower for more or less curve,

Answer (score 0):

Add `border-radius: 50%;` in your css.